# Plotting function and quiver results to same figure problem

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

In the code below, I have tried to find out the working principle of gradient in python and plotting its results.

When I run the code without `plt.plot(x,f)`, the gradient vectors seem reasonable according to my knowledge (except the x-axis because it is not between -100 and 100 and I don't know why). However, when I tried to see these vectors on function line, I have problems. My code is as follows:

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = mgrid[-100:101:1]
f = x**2

Ex = gradient(f)

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.gca()
ax.quiver(x,Ex)
ax.plot(x,f)
plt.show()
```

I was just wondering if anyone could see where I have gone wrong, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the [quiver documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.quiver.html) you will find the *call signatures*:

> ```
> quiver(U, V, **kw)
> quiver(U, V, C, **kw)
> quiver(X, Y, U, V, **kw)
> quiver(X, Y, U, V, C, **kw)
> ```

These are the ways the positional arguments will be understood. That means that in your case, it is understanding `x` as `U` and `Ex` as `V`, being `U` and `V` the x and y components of the arrow vectors respectively. Thus, as no x nor y positions for the vectors are supplied, it plots the arrows from 0 to the length of the array, each arrow starting at an integer position, in your case, from 0 to 200.

The first thing to notice in order to solve the problem is that `quiver`'s description is **Plot a 2-D field of arrows.**. It is an intrinsecally 2-D function. Therefore, to achieve your desired output, we have to supply the x and y positions of the arrows, which are `x` and `f`. And also, its x and y arrow components, which can be easily calculated from the gradient `Ex`. The gradient is roughly *dy/dx*, so once the gradient *f'* is known, the arrow in the xy plane representing it is *(u,v)=(l,f'*l)* where *l* is the spacing in the `x` array.

Eventually, plotting instead with the command:

```
plt.quiver(x,f,np.ones_like(Ex),Ex,angles='xy')
```

solves the problem. The `angles='xy'` makes the arrows point from (x,y) to (x+u, y+v) as it should be in this case.